# Add Textboxes to Userform Frame based on a Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

I want a user to press a button to pull all their "Open" positions into a userform.

I have a Userform with a Frame and a command button to search through Column 3 (named "Status") on a spreadsheet and find the word "Open". Once this word is found I want textboxes to be automatically created inside the frame with the data from the "found" row for columns 4 - 10.

So if one row is found with "Open" then I expect 7 textboxes to be created on the userform. From the picture below I expect 28 textboxes.

When I press the command button nothing happens - no errors - nothing. I tried to use the breakpoints to troubleshoot but nothing was revealed to me to take action on. I am not "seeing" why it is not working here.

I tried moving the code outside the userform and into a module and calling the function but that didn't do anything.

I tried setting the rows I want as constants and creating a separate "AddBox" function to call within the main code but that didn't work but I also didn't understand that code as much as I do the one I am posting now.

Frame Name = Open_Positions_Frame

Command Button Name = open_post_but

Sheet Name = Database

[image: Database Sheet View]

[image: Userform Frame/Button]

```
Public Sub open_post_but_Click() '*****The command Button on the userform Frame*****  

Dim i As Integer ' for the loop
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wk As Worksheet
Dim ctlTextBox As MSForms.TextBox
Dim intCol, intCols As Integer   '******for the columns I want to pull into the userform*****
Dim strCName As String           '******this is to name the textboxes******
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim curColumn  As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wk = wb.Sheets("Database")
curColumn = 3     '*********column index here - Mine starts at Column 3 ********
lastRow = wk.Cells(Rows.Count, curColumn).End(xlUp).row

For i = 3 To lastRow 'Loop through row 3 to last row
    '********If the text "Open" is found in a row in column 3 then
    ' add & fill textboxes with data from Columns 4-10 onto the userform frame******
    If wk.Cells(i, 3) = "Open" Then


        '******Add the textboxes***********
        '*****Columns 4-10 add textbox and give the control a name C# - #is the column*****
         For intCol = 4 To intCols = 10

             strCName = "C" & intCol
             Set ctlTextBox = Open_Positions_Frame.Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1", strCName)
             With ctlTextBox
                 .Top = 10
                 .width = 50
                 .height = 20
                 .Left = (intCol) * 60
                 .Value = intCol
             End With
         Next
        '********************************
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED and TESTED**

You were writing the text boxes on top of each other. i added a separater by row.

```
Public Sub open_post_but_Click()
'you might want to experiment with these.
Const curColumn As Long = 4 'index will start a column 4 "Status"
Const theWidth As Long = 66 'you might experiment with these
Const theRowDifference As Long = 20


Dim i As Long, intCol As Long, rowspacer As Long
Dim ctlTextBox As MSForms.TextBox


Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim wk As Worksheet: Set wk = wb.Sheets("Database")
Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = wk.Cells(Rows.Count, curColumn).End(xlUp).row


For i = 3 To lastRow
    For Each cl In wk.Cells(3, curColumn)
        If InStr(1, cl.Value, "Open", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        rowspacer = rowspacer + theRowDifference

      '******Add the textboxes***********
          For intCol = 5 To 11

             Set ctlTextBox = Open_Positions_Frame.Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1")
                 With ctlTextBox
                   .Top = rowspacer
                   .width = theWidth
                   .height = 20
                   .Left = intCol * 60
                   .Name = "openPosBox" & intCol
                   .Value = wk.Cells(i, intCol).Value
                 End With
            Next intCol
       '********************************
        End If
    Next cl
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for finding those. I made those changes but it had no effect.

Comment: @AprilParker I found a couple other things that might need changes. Your value wasn't set correctly and you're name the textbox the same thing each time.

Comment: Thanks PG, however, the changes you added had no effect. I think the code skips over creating the textboxes because it isn't finding the "Open" If statement I have based on debugging. I made some more changes and I got 1 row of textboxes to populate but not the rest. It appears the code is not finding my "Open" condition. I created a "mock" excel file of my problem and placed it in Dropbox if you want to see it. If you have any more ideas let me know. The link is: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/z2zx9mhrziaq7o9/AADwUsbpruoJbOf-cak-0Y4la?dl=0

Comment: @AprilParker I looked at your file and saw the issue. The boxes are writing on top of each other. I adjusted the code slightly to include some spacers. you need to just experiment with the positions of each box. Assuming this works, I would appreciate it if you would click accept as this did take me a bit of time to troubleshoot. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks PG, The textboxes was a huge headache for me. I didn't realize they were stacking. I appreciate the time you took to figure that out. The code still is pulling all cells that have a value instead of my condition statement of status=open but I worked on it a little more and figure that out. I have to get rid of the Instr() function. It wasn't working. I will mark your response as a answer and add mine for others. Thanks again so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

PGSystemTester helped figure out the stacking textbox issues - Huge thank you! However, I was still struggling with my If Condition statement. I managed to figure it out and I am adding the complete code as an answer for anyone needing this use case

```
Public Sub open_post_but_Click()
Const curColumn As Long = 4 'index will start a column 4 "Status"
Const theWidth As Long = 70 'you might experiment with these
Const theRowDifference As Long = 20

Dim i As Long, intCol As Long, rowspacer As Long
Dim ctlTextBox As MSForms.TextBox

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim wk As Worksheet: Set wk = wb.Sheets("Database")
Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = wk.Cells(Rows.Count, curColumn).End(xlUp).row

Dim status As String
status = "Open"


For i = 3 To lastRow
   If Cells(i, curColumn).Value = status Then 'took on the Instr() function and added this instead, textboxes will only be created if the column 4 status is "Open"
    rowspacer = rowspacer + theRowDifference

  '******Add the textboxes***********
      For intCol = 4 To 11

         Set ctlTextBox = Open_Positions_Frame.Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1")
             With ctlTextBox
               .Top = rowspacer
               .width = theWidth
               .height = 20
               .Left = intCol * 40
               .Name = "openPosBox" & intCol
               .Value = wk.Cells(i, intCol).Value
             End With
        Next intCol
   '********************************
    End If
 Next i
 End Sub
```